# How to disable the Debugging Console of Raylib, without disabling also the other outputs?

Tags: c, gcc, console, printf, raylib

Sometimes I want to print the value of a variable (or something else) in the console with printf. The problem is that, when compiling the C-Programm with GCC and adding the flags "-Wl,--subsystem,windows", not only Raylib prints are disabled but also the other prints. Is it possible to disable JUST the prints of raylib?

Until now I tried so:
gcc main.c -O3 -o snake.exe -lm -lz -lcurl -O1 -Wall -std=c99 -Wno-missing-braces -I include/ -L lib/ -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -lcurl -Wl,--subsystem,windows && snake.exe

What do I have to change?

Comment: I’ll preface this comment by saying I know nothing about raylib. This is a bandaid solution at best but if raylib only outputs it’s debug information to one output stream (i.e only stdout or stderr) then you could pipe that output to a file or /dev/null then print your debug information into the other stream.

Comment: I solved it:  SetTraceLogLevel(LOG_ERROR); for just enabeling raylib errors